# Why can no commercial laser products achieve a frequency stability of $< 1 \ \text{Hz}$?

Tags: optics, laser, photonics, laser-cavity

I am currently studying the textbook *Laser Systems Engineering* by Keith Kasunic. Chapter **1.2.1 Temporal coherence** says the following:

> Even a frequency-stabilized SLM laser has a linewidth – an unavoidable consequence of random spontaneous-emission phase variations resulting from quantum fluctuations in excited-state energy levels. For such lasers, the ideal single-mode (Schawlow-Townes) linewidth $\Delta \nu_{\text{ST}}$ for a laser cavity $\Delta \nu_{\text{R}}$ (not its etalon) is given by Refs 9 and 12 as
> $$\Delta \nu_{\text{ST}} = \dfrac{\pi h \nu \cdot (2 \pi \Delta \nu_{\text{R}})}{P} \ \ \ \text{[Hz]} \tag{1.8}$$
> where $P$ is the output power of the given axial mode. Physically, the higher power has a larger fraction of amplified in-phase photons in comparison with the incoherent, out-of-phase photons from spontaneous emission, reducing $\Delta \nu_{\text{R}}$ of the laser's axial modes [also Eq. (1.7)] given the laser-cavity reflectivity $R$.
>
> Equation (1.8) represents the ultimate lower limit on linewidth, with no commercial products able to achieve this level of frequency stability ($< 1 \ \text{Hz})$. In practice, some SLM fibre lasers have a linewidth smaller than $10 \ \text{kHz}$ – limited by "technical noise" (fluctuations in optical and optomechanical parameters, e.g.), and resulting in a coherence length $d_c \ge 15 \ \text{km}$.

For details, the Wikipedia article regarding Eq. (1.8) can be found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laser_linewidth#History:_First_derivation_of_the_laser_linewidth).

I'm curious about this part:

> Equation (1.8) represents the ultimate lower limit on linewidth, with no commercial products able to achieve this level of frequency stability ($< 1 \ \text{Hz})$. In practice, some SLM fibre lasers have a linewidth smaller than $10 \ \text{kHz}$ – limited by "technical noise" (fluctuations in optical and optomechanical parameters, e.g.), and resulting in a coherence length $d_c \ge 15 \ \text{km}$.

Why can no commercial products achieve a frequency stability of $< 1 \ \text{Hz}$, and
how does (1.8) show this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the meanwhile there are commercial laser systems with stability below 1 Hz.<sup>[[1](https://www.menlosystems.com/products/ultrastable-lasers/)]</sup> However, this is still very challenging. Your equation $(1.8)$ is the [Schawlow-Townes linewidth](https://www.rp-photonics.com/schawlow_townes_linewidth.html), which can be understood as the fundamental physical lower limit for laser linewidth. In reality other effects are dominating. If the optical length of the laser resonator changes due to

- temperature
- mechanical vibrations
- changes in the composition of the gas in the resonator

its resonance frequency and therefore the frequency of emission changes. Consider a resonator with a round-trip length of $L = 1 \, \text{m}$ emitting at a frequency of $f = 500 \, \text{THz}$. Then the length change $\Delta L$ which changes the resonance frequency by $\Delta f = 1 \, \text{Hz}$ is
$$\Delta L = L \frac{\Delta f}{f} = 2 \, \text{fm} \text{.}$$
To achieve such a stability one needs to eliminate all fluctuations in the environment carefully and isolate the system well. Additionally one needs to actively regulate the cavity length, for example by a mirror mounted on a [piezo crystal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piezoelectricity#Actuators). As frequency reference one uses monolithic well-isolated [ultrastable external cavity](https://www.rp-photonics.com/reference_cavities.html). This is more stable than the laser cavity, because it doesn't have any active elements besides temperature stabilization. Even better frequency references can be optical transitions in atoms<sup>[[2](https://doi.org/10.1038/s41586-020-3006-1)]</sup>, but I don't know of any commercial system yet.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. There's still one thing I'm confused about: If the Schawlow-Townes linewidth is the fundamental physical lower limit for laser linewidth, then how can we get below $1 \ \text{Hz}$, which the author says is physically impossible due to the same equation? Is the equation actually invalid somehow? Or was one of the original Schawlow-Townes assumptions incorrect (since, as your article states, the equation was discovered *before* even the demonstration of the first laser)?

Comment: @ThePointer As far as I understand the quote they mean that there was no commercial laser system with a linewidth below $1 \, \text{Hz}$ at the time of writing. But this is not a typical value for the Schawlow-Townes limit. In the case described in my answer with the $L = 1 \, \text{m}$ resonator assuming a [finesse](https://www.rp-photonics.com/finesse.html) of $100$ and an output power of $P = 1 \, \text{W}$ the Schawlow-Townes limit is $\Delta f_{\text{ST}} = 18.7 \, \text{µHz}$.

Comment: Ahh, ok; in that case, I misinterpreted what the author was saying. Thanks for taking the time to clarify this.